How could ear plugs resistant to extremely loud sounds function?
In my story I have a character with the ability to emit powerful electric blasts. These electric blasts as you can imagine emit extremely large amounts of sound, heat, light, and obviously current. I have already found ways to make this character resistant to the heat  light, and current produced by lightning blasts however I have not found a method of making this character more resistant to the loud sound produced by their electric based attacks. So how could an electrokinetic character become resistant to the immense thunder produced by their attacks?

The sound is about 200 decibels.
The tech level is about modern day.
A form of earplugs or headphones can be used.
If the sound level is too high then could there be a way to direct it away from the user?


At 200dB, the pressure wave is strong enough to damage a whole lot more than just your ears. A sufficiently loud sound can injure or kill, not just deafen. Ear protection won't keep your lungs from rupturing.

The maximum intensity of a sound is 191 dB, where the sound pressure is one atmosphere. Sound pressure cannot be greater than one atmosphere, because air pressure cannot go below zero. Anything above 191 dB is a shock wave, not a sound.

Why aren't standard firing range earplugs adequate for your purpose? I have an old pair that has a valve that closes if a noise is loud enough, little rubber things with a metal core and a sort of rubber skirt that works a bit like an all around ring-barb to give it a solid seal in the ear, you practically have to screw them in, allows better hearing than the bog standard foam earplugs without having to remove them.

That ^ aside, at the level of sound you're asking about ear plugs are not going to help, so I suspect you may be operating from a position of ignorance? give this a read you can be as deaf as a post, a creature with no sense of hearing at all and a 'loud' enough sound will still kill you, sound is a pressure wave in atmosphere and if it's loud enough that's going to do physical damage to flesh and organs just like the pressure wave of a big enough explosion will .. so your asking about "ear plugs" suggests you aren't aware of that?

"I have not found a scientific based method of making this character more resistant to the loud sound" make him wedge shaped and made of steel ;p only works if his pointy end is oriented towards the approaching sound/shockwave .. alternatively make his outer 'skin' a few hundred yards of foam and bubble wrap, which will collapse and compact absorbing the force of the shockwave, going to be a bit cumbersome and increasingly less effective to repeat blasts, he's going to waddle a bit ;D .. third option 'shout back' a shockwave in the opposite direction to the incoming one.

@Pelinore I forget the exact limit but earplugs are limited to something around 30db even if they were absolutely perfect.  The thing is the sound also comes through the body.  Current performance isn't too far below the limit.

@LorenPechtel fully aware (see second comment), at which point the question of earplugs becomes moot, if you're sound is rippling through flesh sufficiently to 'hear' it and do damage to the inner ear despite earplugs there are other structures in the body getting damaged as well making the OPs mention and concern about earplugs a nonsense.

Relax the sound level to something realistic, und just use of the shelf noise cancelling earplugs with transparency mode. They do exactly what you want.

Gratefully, you've tagged this question magic and not science-based. Yay! I can ignore your "science based" comment and help you rationalize the issue for your readers.
The "simple" solution
The ear canal of your super person is different than we mortal humans. When an electrical blast is emitted, muscles automatically close the ear canal on both sides of the ear drum and bring soft tissue against both sides of the ear drum such that the ear is entirely protected from the sound resulting from the blast.
The "complex" solution
As mentioned in comments, sound of the power you're talking about will do all kinds of nasty to the insides of a person. So let's say instead that your super person has the ability to, well, basically become a body full of foam capable of evenly distributing the energy through the body such that nothing can be hurt. Your super would look puffy and couldn't do this for very long (since the blood kinda stops flowing and he/she stops breathing).
So, what sciency basis does this all have?
I'm drawing these ideas from liquid breathing, the idea that you can fill a diving suit full of a super-oxygenated liquid that would allow a oceanic diver to dive to much deeper depths (much higher pressures). One of the reasons this can work is that the pressure against the body is much more uniform and distributed.
Does such a suit exist? Not that I know of. But that shouldn't stop a good story. So I'm applying this idea to your super.

"muscles automatically close the ear canal" muscles aren't going to react fast enough, they need a signal from nerves which in turn needs a signal from sensory organs to react to which is too late even if you short wire it and don't loop to the brain first because it's that signal being received you want to block so damage already done by the time the muscles twitch .. what you want is probably some sort of 'sonic valve'?

200 DB is enough to kill you regardless of what your eardrums do. The brain, lungs, gut, and and bowels are especially vulnerable because the brain doesn't like being shaken, and the rest have air inside them to shake around. The complex solution is certainly possible. If they have a magic body, they can resist it. Generally stuff like muscles, the heart, other things which don't have air and which aren't that sensitive to being shaken around are fine.

@Pelinore If you are the one casting the spell, then you can seal your ears and do whatever other protective stuff you need to before you caste.  You don't have to wait for biofeedback.

Your body to foam idea is find, but the liquid breathing thing does not make sense to me. Lightning creates a powerful shockwave and liquids propagate shockwaves and loud noises much better than air does. So, if you want to make yourself a magic shield, better to surround yourself in a vacuum than in a liquid.

@Pelinore They will in the OP's [tag:magic] powered super person.

@NepeneNep The question is tagged [tag:magic]. All I've done is given the OP the ability to rationalize why their magical super person can survive the blast. And something a lot of people have been forgetting here lately, Real Life cannot be an overriding limitation on any question unless specifically requested. We are not physics-lite.

@Nosajimiki Keep in mind that it was merely the idea that I used to base my answer on. I made (and make) no claim that the effects of lightning could be withstood by liquid breathing. Do we care? The goal is suspension of disbelief, not a boring documentary.

Yeah, they edited it to remove science based headphones. Before they wanted earphones based on modern science which could resist it. Magic can do whatever so it's fine. They did specifically ask about that.  I was just noting, 200DB sound doesn't care what you do with your ears.

@JBH Sure, all I did was identify a small logical fallacy with blocking a sensory feature to avoid damage received from excessive levels of the thing it senses .. you can't react until after you're ears hear the thing, by which time the damage is already done ;) he's magic of course so maybe he has low levels of short term precognition and closes his ears before the damaging sound arrives to tell him  it's coming ;D .. of course if it's always on then no problem, he's just hard of hearing all the time ;D .. an at will feature he can use when he sees or thinks it's needed he can get caught out.

@Pelinore If I'm reading the answer correctly, the muscles weren't contracting in response to the shockwave, but in response to the preparation to emit the pulse.  Separatix gave a real life example of this pattern with bats in their answer.

@CortAmmon if that's the way around it is then it works yes.

@CortAmmon Exactly! Thanks!

You would die immediately
At 150 decibels it's powerful enough to start affecting stuff outside your ears and high tech ear protection can at most limit ear damage up to 170. 200 decibels is like being at the center of ten grenades going off continually. There is nothing that will protect you short of a tank.

Strictly speaking, 200dB does not exist (in Earth's atmosphere), but your body can survive the shockwaves from a lot of things that break the 194dB barrier. Things like grenades  that create a noticeable shockwave actually exceed the dB barrier several fold; so, you hear 150-180dB depending on how it resonates, but a grenade is actually way more energetic than what is needed to hit the dB barrier.

As always, you need an example from nature for this sort of thing. You have a being who has evolved to emit very loud noises, so we shall have a look at a creature that has exactly the same problem
Bats

In terms of loudness, bats emit calls as low as 50 dB and as high as 120 dB, which is louder than a smoke detector 10 centimeters from your ear. That's not just loud, but damaging to human hearing.

Luckily we can't hear them, but critically for the bats' echolocation calls, they do need to hear them

For bats to listen to the echoes of their original emissions and not be temporarily deafened by the intensity of their own calls, the middle ear muscle (called the stapedius) contracts to separate the three bones there--the malleus, incus and stapes, or hammer, anvil and stirrup--and reduce the hearing sensitivity. This contraction occurs about 6 ms before the larynx muscles (called the crycothyroid) begin to contract. The middle ear muscle relaxes 2 to 8 ms later. At this point, the ear is ready to receive the echo of an insect one meter away, which takes only 6 ms. - https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-bats-echolocate-an/

Of course you retain the problems with the volumes you've generated as per
Nepene Nep's answer, but avoiding deafening themselves once you've tuned it down a little is entirely possible.

Frame Challenge: Sound can never exceed 194 dB
Sound is a vibration caused by a wave pattern in the air; so, sounds can only get as loud as the air is able to cause a back and forth motion as a pressure wave propagates.  At 194 db, a sound pattern is in perfect harmony with air causing the interspace between the soundwaves to become a total vacuum.  Instead of sound getting louder at 194 dB, it actually gets distorted and a bit more quiet as the wave pattern disrupts itself. Infact, almost nothing actually reaches a true 194 bB because nothing shy of a very powerful and finely tuned instrument can actually resonate perfectly with the air.  This is why even very energetic events like  firing the giant cannons on a WWII battleship only make sounds in the 150-180 dB range.
So, to answer your question, the actual resonance of your electrical attacks will not perfectly match the air; so, no matter how powerful they are, the sound is unlikely to be outside of the 150-180dB range.  Because of this, any standard gun range or airport rated ear protection is sufficient for pretty much every kind of noise you can possibly be submitted to.
Where does all that extra kinetic energy go you might ask?  It becomes a shockwave.  A shockwave is a single pulse of extra high pressure gas that can accumulate at the outside of an expanding "loud" event.  This shockwave does not cause any extra harmful vibrations in your ears, and most standard ear protection will prevent almost any conceivable shockwave from simply overpressuring your eardrums.  An average lightning strikes can create a shockwave pressure of about 150 lb/in^2; so, if you are casting lightning from your hands, the expanding air will shatter your hands and probably throw your whole body across the room... but if you can emit the blast from the end of a nice wizardry staff several feet ahead of your body, then the initial shockwave will not have a large surface to push against, and it would give the shockwave enough time to spread out before reaching you that it probably won't break any bones.  If you are in really good shape and well braced for the shockwave, you will probably be able to stay on your feet... but I would still imagine it would feel a lot like getting tackled; so, thick pads and a helmet would also be advised.

If you're okay with earplugs/headphones, then there are real-world options that you can use.  There are hearing protectors made for industrial environments that are made of material that specifically blocks loud, sharp sounds.  The model linked above claims to provide almost 42 dB attenuation to higher-frequency sound, but close to half of that for lower frequencies.  They also have electronics that listen to your environment using multiple microphones, filter out loud noises while keeping important sounds like speech, and then replay that audio through speakers.  This protects the wearer from loud noises without sacrificing the ability to hear everything else.  Similar products are made for hunters, who can be subject to sounds nearly as intense as your thunder when they shoulder a rifle and create a 170+ dB explosion mere inches from their ear.  With headsets like these, those loud noises are reduced to safe levels but you can still have a conversation and hear ambient sounds normally.  Some manufacturers even make them in an earbud form factor.
Others have pointed out that a 200 dB sound will cause all sorts of other issues, and these won't protect you from things like that.  I don't think that will be an issue, though, since real-world thunder is usually in the 165-180 dB range (the rare, extremely loud thunder requires certain meteorological conditions that wouldn't be present in artificially-produced lightning).  Many rifles are in that same range, so I suspect that a solution designed for hunters would likely also fit your character's use case.
